# Displaying thumbnails of a set of images

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, image, thumbnails

I have a fixed number of images, given by my client (not coming from the internet or from the camera), and on the click of a button I have to show all the images as thumbnails. How can I perform this operation?

Comment: What have you tried?  You also need to clarify how you want it to lay out.  All images equally divided within one view?  Cycle through them?  n images per view and then you swipe through the pages?  This isn't clear and needs clarification

Comment: on another view all images are equally should be equally divided

Comment: For simple example of displaying set of images in grid view you can refer to example on github https://github.com/camh/CHGridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some open source controls you may want to look at such as:

See the photo browser @
http://three20.info/

Also found this one:
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ktphotobrowser

Or - if you want control ...

You can create your own custom UIView which you pass an array of image names (or reflect over the bundle).  It depends if you want to just add images and have it just work which seems desirable.

In layoutSubviews, you can then equally subdivide out the frames on [self bounds].  Then in each frame (CGRectMake) you can create a UIImageView initWithFrame after creating an UIImage imagedNamed and call setImage. You'll likely want to maintain the aspect ratio so you'll want to calculate max width or height and place in that frame centered or crop it to the square.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[myImage setAlpha:1];
[tableViewButton setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope that helps! And you can set the frames for the position for eat image aswell! :D

Answer (score 0):

Just create a view in your viewController.xib and put UIImageViews at the size that you want on the view. In the viewController.h class type the following:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView* thumb1;
```

Type as many of those statements as you have Image views then proceed back to the xib and go to File's Owner. From File's Owner, select the last tab in the pane on the right and drag each outlet to the respective UIImageView on the view.

Now in your viewController.m class, in the method that is linked to the button that changes the images, simply substitute your image names and IBOutlets into the following code where I have placed ClientImage1.png and thumb1, respectively:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ClientImage1.png"];
[thumb1 setImage:image];
```

Just duplicate that code for each thumbnail you need to display (for each UIImageView you have on your view) and that should take care of it for you.

EDIT:

*Just for clarity, these UIImageViews don't need to be on a new view, just make sure that if they are, you code the system to change views while displaying the thumbnails.*

END EDIT

I hope this helps you.

Comment: That means you would add another variable and outlet whenever an image is added?  I think it needs a dynamic layout by passing a list of images (or better yet, reflecting over the images in the bundle).